# How to raise a number to a power geometrically.

Tags: geometry, exponentiation

There are methods to add two lines of arbitrary lengths or multiply them together known since Greek times; and more advanced methods based on the concepts of bases and units.

But, I have not been able to find a way to exponentiate a number geometrically without using algebra. I would love if someone could somehow illustrate the concept.

Basically I am asking is it possible to draw the graph of a^x geometrically.

On questions raised by Aretino and RickyDemer I want to clarify that:
I am talking about Euclidean geometry (so a collapsible compass,straight-edge are allowed); although, Cartesian geometry is fine, too.

Also, is there a book that can teach a basic concept as this? You know, a book on Euclidean geometry that teaches exponentiation, multiplication etc.

Comment: For integer exponents, you could consider $a^n$ as the volume of an $n$-dimensional cube with side lengths of $a$

Comment: @Christian What about fractional exponents? And, how exactly can I illustrate the concept on n-dimensional cube in Euclidean geometry?

Comment: do you mean to construct a number $a^n$ from a given segment of length $a$ and $1$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube ​ ​

Comment: @ShubhamKumar Yes, I do realize a unit will be necessary as a^1 will otherwise be meaningless.

Comment: @AbdurRahman : ​ ​ ​ a^1 = a ​ regardless of what unit is chosen. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @AbdurRahman My apologies; I had misinterpreted the question. After seeing what you meant my comment is hardly applicable

Comment: @RickyDemer You did choose '1' as a unit. I am talking about Euclidean geometry. I give you line-segment A and tell you to raise it to the power a line-segment B; not algebraically. How can you do it without knowing whether line-segment B is less than or greater than a unit?

Comment: I can't "do it ... than a unit". ​ That doesn't stop a^1 from being meaningful even when 1 isn't. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Already raising a segment to power $1/3$ is impossible using straightedge and compass. Which instruments would be allowed?

Comment: @RickyDemer I am sorry your comment is entirely incomprehensible. The second part though; you see I am talking about just Euclidean geometry. We are taught how to exponentiate algebraically, but, I want to find a meaning without algebra. Sorry, if I have offended you.

Comment: @Aretino I did not know that. I should edit my question. Also, can you please provide the theorem you are talking about? I know only college level mathematics. : )

Comment: He's talking about the theorem on [the page my initial comment linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube#Proof_of_impossibility). ​ ​

Comment: @Christian Well, thank you for admitting that. I do not know much about n-dimensions and all that.

Comment: @RickyDemer Ahhh! Basically it is is not possible to geometrically construct a^x where the outcome is irrational. So, we cannot construct 2^(1/3) since it is irrational. Have I understood right?

Comment: No, since the Pythagorean Theorem gives an easy method of constructing _some_ irrational ratios. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I did know that for the under-root of 2.  But, it is impossible to raise a line-segment to certain powers, if I am right.

Comment: For integer powers (positive, negative, or zero), see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1396400/409).

Answer (score 3):

Let $AB = 1$, $AD=a$. We draw another line at any angle with $AB$, mark a point C on it such that $AC=a$. Let a line through $D$ parallel to $BC$ meet this line at $E$[image], then $AE=a^2$, continuing this way we can raise it to any integer power.

Using this you can only calculate negative integral powers as well. Calculation of square roots is simple so we can construct all numbers of form $a^\frac{n}{2}$. But we cannot go cube roots or anything as using scale and compass we are limited to square roots.

Comment: Does it also work for fractional or negative powers? Also, could you provide a source where I could get a wee bit more insight. Thank you.